# Creating Json file with C# of mysql data

Tags: c#, mysql, json

I tried to create a json file of mysql database and it works with the code down below but i dont know how to give them a "header" that i need to fetch data from this json with volley in android studio i need:
 **this is only an example to let you know which section i need , i dont need "colors" **

```
 {
     **"colors"**: [//   i need this section here but with my code i couldnt 
   //get this.
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
       "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
       "hex": "#000"
      }
 }
```

VOLLEY in android studio does this to get data :

> JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("**colors**");

Heres my code in C# for creating a Json file at localhost

```
namespace MySqlServerDemo
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Write( ListJson() );

        }

        //    [WebMethod]
        public static string ListJson()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=studentdetails;password=MYPASSWORD");
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from STUDENTS", con);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            da.Fill(ds);

                List<students> studentDetails = new List<students>();
                studentDetails = ConvertDataTable<students>(ds.Tables[0]);

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return js.Serialize(studentDetails);

            }

        public class students
        {
            public string firstname { get; set; }
            public string surname { get; set; }

        }


        private static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)
        {
            List<T> data = new List<T>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                T item = GetItem<T>(row);
                data.Add(item);
            }
            return data;
        }
        private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
        {
            Type temp = typeof(T);
            T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
                        pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you are converting your color class? The code you are showing loads a class of students

Comment: that was just an example to let you know which section i need so it would be like this for mine :         **student**:[{ firstname: jacob   surname: hello}]

Comment: You have to make your class serializable. For exemple, your class student contains an object StudentInfo which has all the property you want to show, then make both serializable by using the header [Serializable] above your class declaration

Comment: could you maybe write how to do this im not sure where exactly i should write "serializable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write a wrapper class like so.

```cs
public class ContainerClass {
    public List<students> Students {get;set;}
}
```

and serialize that.

So what you would end up doing in your ListJson method is:

```cs
                var studentDetails = new ContainerClass();
                studentDetails.Students = ConvertDataTable<students>(ds.Tables[0]);

                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return js.Serialize(studentDetails);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: this worked thank you! But i cant get the data in android but that will be subject of another question.