# Cant get data from JSON array with android-volley into custom listview

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Accordingly to my last question:
[Creating Json file with C# of mysql data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284928/creating-json-file-with-c-sharp-of-mysql-data)
I tried to fetch the data from created JSON url/file but it just doesnt load the page requested and doesnt give any errors at android emulator.
Here is my Volley code:

```
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.studentss);
    allstudents=new ArrayList<>();
    student_lists=findViewById(R.id.students_listview);

    postClass=new PostClass(allstudents,this);
    student_lists.setAdapter(postClass);
    mQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);     

    jsonParse()

    private void jsonParse(){
    String url=".......WebForm1.aspx";
    JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
    url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
      JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("Students");
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject stu =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String stuName=stu.getString("firstname");

                            allstudents.add(stuName);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);

}
```

I would really appreciate if you could show me my fault. I think the problem  has to do something with android not json becuase **i can get the data but not display it!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `onResponse()` after getting the response , you need to set up your listView with updated Data.

add this code in `onResponse()`

```
postClass=new PostClass(allstudents,this);
student_lists.setAdapter(postClass); or  postClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

do like this -

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response . getJSONArray ("Students");
            for (int i = 0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject stu = jsonArray . getJSONObject (i);
                String stuName = stu . getString ("firstname");

                allstudents.add(stuName);
            }

       postClass=new PostClass(allstudents,this);//THİS LİNE GIVES AN ERROR LIKE THIS BUT ONLY USING THE NEXT LINE WOULD BE EFFICIENT AND ALSO SOLVE THE PROBLEM JUST WANTED TO EDIT
```

:postClass
(ArrayList,
android.app.Activity)
in PostClass cannot be applied
to
(ArrayList,
anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener)"

```
        postClass.notifyDataSetChanged();//THIS LINE IS ENOUGH 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @jacob hope fully this answer will solve your problem , feel free to accept this answer

Comment: Thank you very much this also a solution i found another way at the same time you posted  this :) but i will accept your answer as solved :)

Comment: in your answer you are notifying Adapter in for loop , thats not good practice , i updated my code as ur likeable solution , first add all student in arraylist and then notify the adapter , it will be efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points you have to check:
1- 'Student' is the correct name in your Json not 'student'.
2-Structure of the JSON result Object->Array->Object.

I personally prefer to use GSON as it can automate the conversion without looping manually.

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrongly here but in my code its the same as you said i will try gson thank you but i think with the method "getString" the problem you mentioned should be solved?

Comment: No it didnt sorry

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding:

```
 allstudents.add(stuName);
 postClass.notifyDataSetChanged(); //THİS LİNE SOLVED İT
```